# Exclude a project from workspace clearing done by SWTBot

Tags: eclipse, junit

I am running a SWTBot Test (based on JUnit 4). This test creates a project (with UI), checks some stuff, and clears the workspace afterwards. Here is a screenshot, where I activated the workspace-cleaning:

[image]

But there is one project that I want to KEEP in the workspace. So my question: How can i exclude a specific project from that "clear workpsace" option?

I am using Eclipse 3.7 und Junit 4. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do that through the Run Configuration interface. You could leave the clean flag on and re-import the project in your test setup.

```java
IPath projectPath = new Path("[TODO]"); // The absolute path location of your project root
IPath projectDescriptionLocation = new Path(projectPath.resolve(".project").toString());
IProjectDescription description = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().loadProjectDescription(projectDescriptionLocation);
IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(description.getName());
project.create(description, null);
project.open(null);
```